# Will search engines skip role="presentation"?

Tags: images, seo

```
<img src="/..." alt="Description">
<p>Description</p>
```

Above is a sample where screen readers will mention the word "Description" twice.  What would be the best way to make screenreaders read these lines without redundancy and not impacting SEO.

```
<img src="/..." alt="Description" role="presentation">
```

will this line be skipped by search engines?